# Support Action Bar

Tags: android, xml

I am having an issue when I applied the toolbar into the app and it crashed when I try to run the app.

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />
```

Main.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application android:name="com.example.app.AppController" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Logcat:

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest is wrong, i.e. applying the theme for the application.

Change it to:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Because currently you use a style WITH action bar.

Comment: Yes,as he said,change that line in the manifest and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In my code only I disabled the line :
//setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

on main class